# Django Database Design: ManyToManyField when using Inlines

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to design my first database and got a little bit stuck. The design is as follows: You have an author who can have many books. Each book can have many pages. Each page can have many pictures. Each page is unique (`ForeignKey`). Pictures may not be unique (you can use the same picture in different pages/books, so this should be `ManyToMany`). **My problem is that I can't get the pictures to be a `ManyToManyField` when using `Inlines`.**

If I change ForeignKey to ManyToMany, I get the exception "`<class 'books.models.Picture'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'books.models.Page'>`". I had a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714995/inline-editing-of-manytomany-relation-in-django), but have no clue how to apply this in my case.

This is how my models.py looks like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    contents = models.TextField(max_length=15999)

class Picture(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page) # ideally, this should be many-to-many
    picture_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

In my admin interface, I'd like to have all the books an author wrote on the author page. Also, I'd like to have all pages of a book in the books page and so on. My admin.py therefore looks like this:

```
class PictureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'picture_uuid')

class PictureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Picture

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'page_uuid')

    inlines = [
        PictureInline,
        ]

class PageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title')

    inlines = [
        PageInline,
        ]

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'email')

    inlines = [
        BookInline,
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `ManyToManyFields` directly as inlines. Inlines must have a foreign key back to the model being edited, and of course the actual child does not. If you want to edit a M2M inline, the best you can do is use the `through` table, so you'd need to alter your `InlineModelAdmin` like so:

```
class PictureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page.pictures.through
```

Which requires that the `ManyToManyField` be on the `Page` model:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    ...
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(Picture)
```

Comment: Works very well, except that I have now two sections on a page where I can select pictures. One foreign key drop-down menu to select a picture and one normal many-to-many menu to select a picture. How can I get rid of the second?

Comment: Just add the actual field to your `ModelAdmin`'s `excludes`

Comment: Thanks, just done that and it disappeared. Next problem, however: if I try to put the same picture on a page again, I'll get the error (in the Django Admin interface): "Page-picture relationship with this Page and Picture already exists." Why is this so? I thought this is now a many-to-many relationship, i.e. I should be able to have the same picture on a page twice or three times or four times etc.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I didn't realise you could assign the through table directly as the model in an inlineadmin. Thanks for this.

Comment: Generally, no, you don't add the same relation to the same model twice. I've never thought about even doing that before because I've never had a need. It's possible that the default intermediary table that Django creates for an M2M relationship enforces a unique together constraint on the two foreign keys. You might be able to get around that by creating your own `through` model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Neither did I for the longest time. Don't even remember now where I stumbled upon that info. It's still not as good as being able to inline the actual model directly, but it's something ;).

Comment: Actually, you are right. I don't have a need either. I can define in my layout field that picture such and such appears 3 or 4 times. Thanks so much for your help! One last question if I may: I assume that I may end up with 1000s of pictures and loading the drop-down would take some time (I guess). I tried to show pictures as raw id's but this didn't work (i.e. Django didn't really care when I put raw_id_fields = ("pictures",) in my PageAdmin class. It still gave me the same old drop down).

Comment: You have to put `raw_id_fields` on your *inline* class. `InlineModelAdmin`s (for the most part) have all the same functionally as regular `ModelAdmin`s. Things like fieldsets, excludes, etc. are defined on the `InlineModelAdmin` just like they would be on `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I put it in my inline class (PictureInline) I get the error message 'PictureInline.raw_id_fields' refers to field 'pictures' that is missing from model 'Page_pictures'.

Comment: i.e. right now I have `class PictureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page.pictures.through
    raw_id_fields = ("pictures",)`

Comment: That's because the field on the `through` model is not "pictures" it's `picture`.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, it works!! Thanks so much, this was really really helpful. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models you have to define a `model` attribute in your inline

Comment: Umm... He did. And, that's not the issue anyways.

Comment: @ChrisPratt if you see the link i pointed at you'll notice that my answer is pretty much the same as yours, when i said define a Model i meant model = Page.pictures.through

Comment: Then why post an answer that merely suggests the same thing as my answer?

Comment: WHen i was answering this my page hadn't refreshed :)